# Auto-change focus while typing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need the focus to be automatically transferred to the second field after 4 entered characters in the first field.

```
<input type="text" id="input1">
<input type="text" id="input2">

$("#input1").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length == 4) {
        $("#input2").focus();
    }
});
```

But it does not work. What am I missing? I've tried also

```
document.getElementById("input2").focus();
```

But it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to use `keyup` event instead of `change` and other logic will work as is

```js
$(function(){
  $("#input1").on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length == 4) {
        $("#input2").focus();
    }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input1">
<input type="text" id="input2">
```

Comment: happy to help you :)